# How to queue file read/writing to hard drive in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, java-server

I have a server which receives requests from thousands of clients connecting tcp sockets, to either read or write data off one hard disc.

I know I need somehow one thread which does all the HD file.IO in this case but how can I pass all those requests from socket connection threads to one master hard-drive manager which will in some sequence do this work and turn the data to the connected socket threads?

Is there a way to queue tasks in this manner?

Comment: Why do you think you need one HD thread? If they're all reading/writing different files just do it inline in the connection thread. You're making a rod for your own back here.

Comment: I was under the impression that mechanical hard drives could only read or write from one location at a time, and so spawning 20,000 threads (from incoming client requests) to create or look at different files simultaneously would simply not work.  
Perhaps I am largely mistaken?

Comment: It will work. There is a queue, in fact several. You don't need to add another one.

Comment: Brilliant. Have a moment to explain what how threads working on HDD innately form an orderly queue?   I'll be delighted to find I've been over complicating things in my head.

Comment: @iForgotMyLogin suppose for a moment that there wasn't a queue (somewhere inside the bowels of the OS). What do you think would happen instead?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, have a look at [producer/consumer pattern](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html) and `BlockingQueue`.

Answer (score -1):

i disagree with what been said here,going for another layer with a manager who consumes data and writes it to the hdd is better and more scalable approach you will free the connection threads to do their natural work and you have one manager to which you can give any desired command such as stop writing to disk or write to distributed other source ,if you are only looking to get things done you may choose each approach ,kernel wise every time you are writing to disk these command is interpreted to a system call, these system call will go through cache to check for existing data blocks untill it reaches the the actual request then this request is queued with all other requests in the system and some other disk thread will fetch your request that means your connection thread may be unavailable if its waiting for a response,in that time that thread could have done some work .

Comment: This is not an answer.